# file_put_contentsで生成されたファイルはどのディレクトリに格納される？

Tags: php

file_put_contentsで生成されたphpファイルはどのディレクトリに格納されますか？

指定によりますか？

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contens` の第一引数にファイル名を指定するので、そのファイルが存在するディレクトリになります。(ファイルが存在しなければ書き込み時に作成)

[PHP: file_put_contents - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.file-put-contents.php)

```php
file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
```